# How to get impulse response plot of RLC cicuits

Tags: circuit-analysis

I want to plot impulse response of different RLC circuit.
Which software is easy and situated for it? as i am a starter.

Comment: Octave or matlab. You should drive the circuit TF and pass it to the octave `impulse()` function

Comment: There is a matlab toolbox to simulate such circuit

Answer (score 1):

LTSpice is a free circuit simulation software:
http://www.linear.com/designtools/software/#LTspice

With this you can create the circuit you want to model, and then stimulate the circuit with different inputs (impulses, sine waves etc).  You can then view plots of current / voltage at locations you choose in the circuit.

Answer (score 0):

We offer 2 free tools at robustcircuitdesign.com : SCE models SNR/ENOB and electric/magnetic/VDD/GND interference for embedded systems. SWE provides canned examples of Impulse Response, for LRC and ActiveFilters and ClassB amplifiers. >>>>>>You want to download SWE.<<<<<<

The tool, Signal Wave Explorer, is free to download and requires no SPICE skills. It takes only 3 mouse clicks ["Example", "Scope Probe Ringing", "Run"] to produce waveforms & Spectra. Examples, which are canned but editable for LRC values plus OpAmp params, range from LRC ringing to OpAmp filters with horrid high-frequency rejection[per Walt Jung], and ClassB power amplifiers with VDD ringing that appears on the output, that ringing NOT a harmonic of the input tone. We picked these examples because of the surprises therein.

The other tool, also free, named Signal Chain Explorer, is explicitly crafted to quantify the interference risks of EFI/HFI/PSI/GPI coupling into the PCB traces of embedded systems. You select the stages, you select the traces between stages, you define the OpAmp Rnoise(Johnson noise) params, you select which interferers are enabled, you click "UPDATE" and view the SNR/ENOB.

After 30 usage-days, the impulse-response tool, named Signal Wave Explorer (SWE), needs a payment of $20 to continue use.

[image]

Here is impulse response of FLAWED active low-pass-filter, as Jung warned. The OpAmp circuit is INVERTING. Except the output has non-inverted copies of the input spike. (cure is to insert C1; C1 is disabled in this simulation)

[image]